# How To Update The Date Based On Previous Record Value

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update, if an employee has a termination_date, then update the next join_date to termination_date - 1 day in postgresql. The first Join_date should not be updated.

Example:

| EmpID | Dept_No | Join_Date | termination_date | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 11 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 | 183 |
| 1001 | 12 | 2020-02-02 | 2020-04-01 | 182 |
| 1001 | 11 | 2020-04-02 |  | 186 |

Below is the output that I am trying to get.

| Dept_No | Join_Date | termination_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 |
| 12 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-04-01 |
| 11 | 2020-04-01 |  |

Below is what I have so far,

```
UPDATE employee e
SET Join_Date =
((termination_date) -INTERVAL '1 DAY')
WHERE termination_date IS NOT NULL;
```

But I am not sure how to add the below conditions,

1. Don't update the first Join_date
2. use the termination_date from the previous record.

Could anyone advice how to add that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `Dept_No` and how is it relevant? Where is the employee's id/name column?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.I have updated the table and Dept_no ( 11- Dept A, 12- Dept B etc) and Dept A, Dept B are stored in different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE employee AS e1
SET Join_Date = e1.Join_Date -INTERVAL '1 DAY'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM employee e2 
  WHERE e2.EmpID = e1.EmpID AND e2.termination_date IS NOT NULL
    AND e2.Join_Date < e1.Join_Date 
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4df490a48c19434dd12a9e1e7c96c6dc).
Results:

| empid | dept_no | join_date | termination_date | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 11 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 | 183 |
| 1001 | 12 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-04-01 | 182 |
| 1001 | 11 | 2020-04-01 | null | 186 |